# Is it bad to check a Properties.Settings setting on every asp.net request?

Tags: asp.net, settings

i am checking a setting (from the settings.settings) in the master page to see whether or not to add a stats tracking code to the page or not. In test environment, this is false, production this is true.

I was wondering if this reads the web.config file every time, or if asp.net will "cache" this setting on application startup or something so it is more readily available.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274762/asp-net-where-how-is-web-config-cached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It's cached and actually comparible to a static property.

Comment: Got a reference for that? (that it's cached)

Comment: It's cached.  Remember the first rule of optimization, BigJoe.