# Performance issue when web.config is really huge

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does it have any major effect on performance/ memory if my web.config is really huge (say, 1000+ entries in <appSettings>)? Is it a good idea to maintain a different custom xml config file for all business specific settings for my app? Thanks.

Comment: 1000+ appSettings must be a nightmare

Comment: Yes it is. I'm just assuming the max possible value. But in reality, It'll never cross 100. Thanks everyone who replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config file is usually just read once and the info cached so I dont think it will have any performance issue.

[ASP.NET: Where/how is web.config cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274762/asp-net-where-how-is-web-config-cached)

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially delay application startup slightly, but since all settings will be read from memory after that, it shouldn't have any performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.Web app config file works when your page load at the first time.So when ever your application is loads the Web app is read and loaded in the memory.So this will create performance issue on your application and better to put non application level settings on xml file.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that loading a large web.config file takes a *significant* amount of time? Compared with everything else that has to happen on startup, I'd expect reading the web.config to be mostly insignificant.

Comment: It will have.How, a web config file with 1000 keys and 10 keys will not load the same time.Well, loading time may or may not be insignificant, depends of the speed the internet connection.