# Is it redundant to put web.config appSettings values into the Cache object?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I thought I would put those settings into Cache and then invalidate them if the web.Config file changes.  Reading some articles make it seem that this is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config file is already cached in memory. Have a look at this question
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274762/asp-net-where-how-is-web-config-cached).

It's automatically refreshed when the file is touched, too.