# How to access cached web config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, web-config

All these days, I was using the below code to get any value from web config.

```
string someValue= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"]
```

When I came to know that [web config is cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274762/asp-net-where-how-is-web-config-cached) and it was explained there that

*...First of all in ASP.NET you want to ensure you access configuration sections through the   HttpContext object's GetSection method (this uses the cached copies managed by ASP.NET)...*

- Is WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings will **always** fetch
  value from web config and not from cache?
- If Yes, How do I fetch config value from cache?

**P.S How caching works with app.config? Is it stored on windows RAM or .. ?**

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the linked question first. I've closed this question as a duplicate of the linked question and deleted my answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders But there was no code given in linked question on how to use HttpContext object's GetSection and Google did not help to understand the same. Hence I raised this question. So if you can help on how to use HttpContext object's GetSection it will be great

Comment: What don't you understand about [`HttpContext.GetSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getsection.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

web.config caching is done by asp.net run-time engine and its transparent to user code. This is done for performance reasons.

Application code with always get updated value of config entry. So developer don't have to worry about value being stale.

Any change to web.config anyway restarts the application, invalidating the in memory cache value.